# Using NodeJs execute Linux commands Face error

Tags: linux, node.js

I used nodeJS for execute linux command but when i execute command than if "myWaveFile.wav" file generated already than ask can you overwite it? [Y/N] . But when using NodeJS execute command that time not ask anything and req. failed after some time.

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var _cmd = "avconv -i /root/builds/SpeechRecognition/records/wave_file.wav  -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 /root/builds/SpeechRecognition/records/myWaveFile.wav";


//ExecCMD function call from other files


exports.ExecCMD = function(_cmd, callback){
exec(_cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr){
    //sys.puts(stdout);
    callback(error, stdout, stderr);
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-exec is meant for executing atomic commands that gets over in one shot. For interactive commands, you need to get access to a shell. Try this - 
https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs

```
require('shelljs/global');
var _cmd = "avconv -i /root/builds/SpeechRecognition/records/wave_file.wav  -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 /root/builds/SpeechRecognition/records/myWaveFile.wav";
echo("Y");
echo("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the Node API docs: [exec](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) returns a [ChildProcess](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin)

So you should be able to do something like:

```
var cmd = exec(_cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});

cmd.stdin.write("Y");
```

You could also try using [spawn](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of exec.
This gives you the ability to listen to stdout and make more informed decisions on what to write on stdin instead of guessing ahead of time

Comment: cmd.stdin.write("Y"); Nver exec. because in function callback exec. before last row exec.

Comment: @GunjanPatel I copy-pasted your code and forgot to remove `callback`, maybe that confused you. But the `cmd.stdin.write("Y")` should be outside the exec block and be called after that function not in its callback.

Comment: This is of course assuming that exec halts and is waiting for input. Not sure what will happen if exec has returned by the time you try to write to stdin

Answer (score 0):

```
exec(_cmd, function puts(error, stdout, stderr){
    //sys.puts(stdout);
    callback(error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

Why do you write function name???

Maybe you need anonymous function right???

```
exec(_cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    //sys.puts(stdout);
    callback(error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

And then you call only callback function with same arguments
dont need anonymous function

```
exec(_cmd, callback);
```

Comment: I dont have issue with that i have execute above command in linux that time if file available than ask me to overwite Y/N but if using NodeJS nothing happen execute command that time background what happen we dont know how can i give ans of that Que. [Y/n]